# babel-node is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

When I try to run a JS file by babel command it is showing:

> "babel-node is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

I had created `1.js` file in this written `"console.log("hello world")"`;
and tried to run with *babel-node* command but it is showing the above-mentioned error.

Comment: Installing the babel-CLI as globally  `npm install -g babel-cli`

Answer (score 33):

you can try install babel's global version

```
npm install -g babel-cli
```

Answer (score 24):

Tried many suggestions and finally, I had to explicitly provide the absolute path to babel-node to get it working in scripts definition section in package.json file.

"start": "nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/index.js"

node - v15.5.1
nodemon - v2.0.7
@babel/node - v7.12.10

Comment: I'm suspecting that line is from a `scripts` definition section in `package.json` file; am I right?

Comment: Latest version 7.13 does seem to require an absolute path, this change fixed it for me as well

Comment: Yeah happened to me today after updating npm not sure why. But this fixes my issue.

Comment: If you could plz update the answer to say where exactly you have included that line of code, that would be helpful, thanks!  So future readers don't have to go into the comments to get that vital info...

Answer (score 15):

Make sure that you have got the babel module so that it can be used.

For example by using `npm install babel-cli` to get a *node_modules* folder.
Then you can find the runnable in *node_module/.bin*.

Comment: I believe this is a typo and O.O. meant npm install babel-cli

Comment: outdated module. can we use @babel/cli ?

Answer (score 10):

a combination of above solutions worked for me:

```
npm install @babel/node
npm install @babel/cli
npm install @babel/core
```

and then I ran `npm start` and it worked.

Answer (score 10):

Adding `npx` to the command might help, so exact binary will be executed

```
nodemon --exec npx babel-node src/index.js
```

Answer (score 8):

For me the issue was solved by installing 'babel-node' globally by running this command:

```
npm install @babel/node -g
```

Comment: You can also install it locally in the project, that would be better for most cases

Answer (score 5):

If your project is based on babel 7, you should run this

```
npm install  @babel/cli @babel/core
```

Answer (score 3):

install @babel/node , i came across the same problem and by installing this solved my problem

Comment: Not worked for me, only worked installing babel-cli

Answer (score 2):

What is currently missing is part of `@babel/node`. Depending on your project dependency you can install:

```
npm install @babel/cli
npm install @babel/node
```

Answer (score 2):

To intall babel packages worked for me

```
npm i @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env --save-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

**"nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/index.js"**

Comment: "start": "nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node src/server.js",

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For those who struggle making it work for node + nodemon, what helped me was:

1. Install these deps:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.14.5",
"@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
"@babel/node": "^7.14.7",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
"nodemon": "^2.0.12"
```

2. You can leave path to babel-node to be relative.

```
"dev": "nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node",
```

Comment: I just had to install @babel/node and @babel/core globally to resolve the issue. My package.json looks like this:  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  },

Answer (score 0):

My issue solved by running this command

```
> npx babel-watch .
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
"start": "babel-node backend/server.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

`npm ci`

(npm clean install removes node modules and then installs them again)

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything here, it still didn't work.  Eventually I got it working by removing the folders containing the executable (which for me was node_modules/.bin/).

Before:

```
"scripts": {
  "babel": "node_modules/.bin/babel src/index.js -o dist/assets/bundle.js"
}
```

After:

```
"scripts": {
  "babel": "babel src/index.js -o dist/assets/bundle.js"
}
```

Comment: So basically you were requesting a specific relative path for you `babel` executable that didn't exist. And after removing that relative path and just executing the `babel` from `PATH` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

***yes i also get this error***
it was resolved  do check

```
 $ npm run dev
```

> server@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon --exec babel-node index

[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `babel-node index.js`
'babel-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

after that I
install nodemon globally then it was resolved.

```
  $ npm install -g nodemon
```

added 2 packages, removed 85 packages, changed 30 packages, and audited 33 packages in 9s

3 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

result was ✅

✅

```
 $ npm run dev
```

> server@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon --exec babel-node index

[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `babel-node index.js`
Server is runing

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you have these dependencies at a minimum in your package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.13.10",
    "@babel/node": "7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.12",
..
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "2.0.7",
...
  }
```

Then check what script you are running. If you see the problem when running `npm run dev` and you have something like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./src/server.js",
..
  },
```

Update your scripts to the following (assuming you don't already have a "start"):

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node ./src/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec npm start",
...
  },
```

Basically, `nodeman` is used during dev to hot reload code changes. `babel-node` itself runs the server, but the issue being faced occurs when installed package is not detected by nodeman.

Although installing `@babel/cli` globally, might *appear* to resolve the issue, it's not needed (and frowned upon: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli)

Answer (score 0):

On some 'locked down' windows servers installing babel will not automatically update the PATH.  In this case you need to manually add the npm path to you PATH environment variable.

In my case npm was installed at: **C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm**

Once the path was updated I could verify babel is working by typing **babel --version** from the command line to verify the correct version is reported and the error message is no longer displayed.