# Node Js - babel-node is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-node

How to solve this issue for Node JS babel-node is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [babel-node is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001054/babel-node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progra)

Comment: No. It does not solve my issue.